# How to drag and drop a file onto a form and display only the file name?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using the following code:

```
 void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Folder.Visible = false;
        Dragndrop.Visible = false;
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (string filePath in files)
            {
                CurrentFiles.Text = filePath.ToString();
            }
        }
```

And would like to have the `CurrentFiles` textbox display the names of the files that were dragged onto the form. Could someone help me with only displaying the name of the files instead of the whole file path?

Comment: Use System.IO.Path.GetFileName().  Proper attribution is required when you copy code from a post on this web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are to use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And also `+=` in your foreach because if you use just `=`. The textbox will end up displaying only the name of the last file.

```
foreach (string filePath in files)
{
    CurrentFiles.Text += Path.GetFileName(filePath) + " ";
}
```

Comment: you don't need to call `.ToString()` on `filePath` as it is already a `string`.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Oh yeah. Thanks. I just corrected his code without noticing that. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Tijesunimi Using this code, I get http://puu.sh/5z22g.png Why does it print the name twice?

Comment: @NoahCordoba How times did you drag the file onto form?

Comment: @NoahCordoba Are you sure it was just once. I tested the code and it printed just once

Comment: @Tijesunimi Yea, I replaced `+=` with `=` and the problem wax fixed.

Comment: @NoahCordoba The problem with using `=` is that when you drag another file, It won't keep the name of the file dragged previously. It would only replace the name. Try dragging a different file to the form and you will understand what I am saying